# Using python list comprehension to modify the list itself, unexpected result?

Tags: python, list, loops, list-comprehension

I tried to make a change to each element in a list `A` in place and have two methods: `use_list_comprehension(A, length)` and `use_plain_loop(A, length)`. The two perform the same operation on elements but generate different results.

**My question is: does python list comprehension first make a copy of `A`, then use that copy as the source to get elements and perform operations on them?**

```py
def arrange(A):
    length = len(A)
    A = use_list_comprehension(A, length) # we get [19, 20, 12, 1, 8]

    # A = use_plain_loop(A, length) # we get [19, 95, 12, 476, 2383]
    return A        


def use_list_comprehension(A, length):
    return [ A[i]+A[A[i]]*length for i in range(length) ]


def use_plain_loop(A, length):
    for i in range(length):
        A[i] += A[A[i]]*length
    return A


print(arrange([4,0,2,1,3]))
```

Comment: The answers are different because the list is actually modified for `use_plain_loop` so when the next values are calculated, it uses the updated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the list comprehension is not making a copy of A, it's making a new list where the value stored in index `i` of that list is `A[i]+A[A[i]]*length`.  Thus, `use_list_comprehension(A, length)` returns a new list and then A is set to that new list in line 3.  `use_plain_loop(A, length)`, on the other hand, actually modifies the list in place, as `A[i] += A[A[i]]*length` replaces the value stored at `A[i]` with `A[i] + A[A[i]]*length`.

Comment: Thank you so much, Jacob, for the prompt answer. A follow-up question would be if `use_list_comprehension(A, length)` takes O(n) space since it creates a new list?

Comment: Yes, `use_list_comprehension(A,length)` would take O(n) space.